# Deactivating Dropdown-Effect

Tags: jquery

I only want to see the Parent Items, not the Child-categories in my menu.
You can see the dropdown-effect when you click on "Info" here: http://ntm.at/r0sa/
I only want to see "Info", not the Sub-Categories. How can i disable that?
The code for my sidebar is:

```
<div id="left-col">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ntm.at/r0sa/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/ngg.slideshow.min.js?ver=1.06"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ngg-slideshow-1-116-1").nggSlideshow( {id: 1,fx:"fade",width:320,height:240,domain: "http://ntm.at/r0sa/",timeout:10000});
  $("li.page_item").click(function(evt){ // trigger

      if($(evt.target).parent().children('ul').size() == 0) 
         return true;

      $(this).children("ul").slideToggle("fast"); // blendet beim Klick auf "dt" die nächste "dd" ein.
      $(this).children("a").toggleClass("closed open"); // wechselt beim Klick auf "dt" die Klasse des enthaltenen a-Tags von "closed" zu "open".
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: you want to know what row's to remove ot do not use in sub-menu whole the menu?

Comment: I can't really see any effect on that site. It's also better to provide self-contained code samples instead of linking to a full site.

Comment: do you want to hide subcategories for all the items are for INFO only

Comment: I want to remove the rows like "Bio, Contact, Pic..." when you click on "INFO". I only want these Items to be shown: ARCHIVE; MEDIA, PARTNERS/LINKS, INFO, PROJECTS, NOTES and the other things should not be shown as a dropdown menu when you click on them...

Comment: yes, i want to hide subcategories!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the code for you

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ntm.at/r0sa/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/ngg.slideshow.min.js?ver=1.06"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ngg-slideshow-1-116-1").nggSlideshow( {id: 1,fx:"fade",width:320,height:240,domain: "http://ntm.at/r0sa/",timeout:10000});
});

</script>
```